# Selecting a COUNT of values, grouped by that same column, distinct on another

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct

Here's a sample schema:

```
| type_id | university_id |
---------------------------
|    1    |      u01      |
|    2    |      u01      |
|    2    |      u01      |
|    3    |      u02      |
|    4    |      u02      |
```

And what I want is a count of the amount of records that have the same `university_id`, the `university_id` itself, and it must not include duplicates of `type_id`, so the result would look like this for the same data given above:

```
| university_id | COUNT(university_id) |
----------------------------------------
|      u01      |          2           |
|      u02      |          2           |
```

Right now I'm trying the following, but it will clearly give me a `COUNT(u01)` of `3` instead of `2`

```
SELECT university_id, COUNT(university_id) FROM table GROUP BY university_id
```

Is it possible to do what I want, and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should count by `type_id` uniquely not by `university_id`

```
SELECT university_id, COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) TotalCount
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY university_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdc6c/3)

Answer (score 1):

You need a `count(distinct)` on the `type_id` column:

```
select university_id, count(distinct type_id)
from table
group by university_id
```